# Logback not creating the logging file

Tags: java, logback, appender

I tried to add a new log file in my project, I updated the logback.xml but when I test the new log file is not created but the log message is placed in another log file.

logback.xml :

```
<appender name="myLogFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${APPL_FULL_PATH}/myLogFile.log</file>
    <append>true</append>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>${APPL_FULL_PATH}/myLogFile.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <pattern>%d{yyyy.MM.dd HH:MM:ss} %p %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="com.package1" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="myLogFile" />
</logger>
<logger name="com.package2" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="myLogFile" />
</logger>
```

In the Java File each time I call the logger by :

```
    private static final Logger myLog = LoggerFactory.getLogger("myLogFile");
    myLog.info("Test Log File");
```

Comment: You likely have a file called the literal `${APPL_FULL_PATH}/myLogFile.log` in the application’s working directory…

Comment: Yes, I have a # logback.properties that conatins :

APPL_FULL_PATH=/logs